# How to create timer in my case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to have my button doing two things.

init a timer to call a function
call the same function

I have something like the following

```
test.prototype.setupEvent= function(){
        var instance = this;

      $('#btn').on('click', function(){
           clearInterval(instance.timer);
           this.showStuff()

           instance.timer=setInterval(function(){
              instance.showStuff()
           },10000);
        })
    }

test.prototype.showStuff= function(btnID){
        //jump to another page
    }
```

My problem is that I want the user be able to see some contents after 10 second when they first click it, however, if they click the button again before 10 second is up, they can see the contents too. I am not sure how to distinguish the two different states with one click event. Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: "init a timer to call a function call the same function" -- please rewrite this part, I don't know what you mean

Comment: can you edit [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yf5XM/1/) to create the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
test.prototype.setupEvent = function () {
    var instance = this;

    $('#btn').on('click', function () {
        //if there is a timer running then clear the timer, show the content and delete the timer reference
        if (instance.timer) {
            clearInterval(instance.timer);
            instance.showStuff();
            delete instance.timer
            return;
        }
        //also you may want to use setTimeout() not setInverval()
        instance.timer = setInterval(function () {
            instance.showStuff();
            delete instance.timer
        }, 10000);
    })
}

test.prototype.showStuff = function (btnID) {
    //jump to another page
}
```